# Convergence of Bayesian time series model (BSTS)

Tags: r, bayesian, forecasting

I am starting to use BSTS package developed by Steve Scott at Google for time series forecasting. And for most cases I put a fairly the number of MCMC iterations to 500. The forecasts look reasonable but I also wanted to understand the convergence of the model. Once step ahead prediction error variance is often taken as a measure to judge the convergence. bsts model returns one.step.prediction.error as part of the model object. for each MCMC iteration I estimated the one step ahead prediction error variance by the sum of squares and plotted that. Here is a snippet of code with the AirPassangers data which is used for all the bsts example in the package

```
data(AirPassengers)
y <- log(AirPassengers)
ss <- AddGeneralizedLocalLinearTrend(list(), y)
ss <- AddSeasonal(ss, y, nseasons = 12)
model <- bsts(y, state.specification = ss, niter = 5000)
pred <- predict(model, horizon = 12, burn = 100)
a <- model$one.step.prediction.error
plot(rowMeans(a ^ 2), type = "l")
```

[image]

Clearly the one-step-prediction-error more or less stays the same. Am I missing something here or is there another way of showing the model convergence. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: check out the diagnostics available in the `coda` package ... ?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @BenBolker

Comment: You seem to be expecting convergence in the convex optimization sense. This is a Bayesian model with posteriors approximated via MCMC. Completely different paradigm. From the looks of it that model has converged nicely.